# SageMaker NodeJS's SDK is not locking the API Version

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker

I am running some code in AWS Lambda that dynamically creates SageMaker models.
I am locking Sagemaker's API version like so:

`const sagemaker = new AWS.SageMaker({apiVersion: '2017-07-24'});`

And here's the code to create the model:

```
await sagemaker.createModel({
        ExecutionRoleArn: 'xxxxxx',
        ModelName: sageMakerConfigId,
        Containers: [{
            Image: ecrUrl
        }]
    }).promise()
```

This code runs just fine locally with `aws-sdk` on `2.418.0`.

However, when this code is deployed to Lambda, it doesn't work due to some validation errors upon creating the model:

> - MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'PrimaryContainer' in params
> - UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Containers' found in params

Is anyone aware of existing bugs in the `aws-sdk` for NodeJS using the SDK provided by AWS in the Lambda context? I believe the SDK available inside AWS Lambda is more up-to-date than `2.418.0` but apparently there are compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed the 'embedded' lambda version of the aws-sdk lags behind. It's actually on `2.290.0` (you can see the full details on the environment here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html)

You can see here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blame/master/clients/sagemaker.d.ts that it is not until `2.366.0` that the params for this method included `Containers` and did not require `PrimaryContainer`.

As you've noted, the *workaround* is to deploy your lambda with the `aws-sdk` version that you're using. This is sometimes noted as a best practice, as it pins the `aws-sdk` on the functionality you've built and tested against.

Comment: I was reflecting over it a little bit and if the API changed from `2.290.0` to `2.418.0` then the API version should also have changed. Therefore, trying to set `2017-07-24` on `2.290.0` should immediately fail. Unfortunately, as of right now, only one API version is available, so I think AWS has been making changes without versioning the APIs.

Comment: I think they only reversion the API (e.g. give a new date) if it is a breaking change. All code written for `2.290.0` will work in `2.418.0`- what they've done is add features (e.g. now you can specify Containers, which makes PrimaryContainer optional).